# Using blocks to limit the scope of variables inside lengthy(taking long operation time) functions, to free up heap quickly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am using Java for a web application. To free up heap of the unneccesary variables objects, is it a better strategy to Using blocks to limit the scope of variables inside lengthy(taking long operation time) functions and thus free up space as quickly as possible ?

I understand splitting methods into smaller ones is a good idea, but even after that I feel the need to use blocks in those smaller functions.

I would use several blocks inside a single functions so that whenever the job of a variable is over is gets out of the scope and garbage collector can clean the space as quick as possible

Comment: Gaming the garbage collector is a bad idea, especially when you don't know anything about the implementation of it.

Comment: Do you think GC will take my opinion so strongly? I am trying to just 'hint'  GC about that my need for those variables is over. Anyways we use blocks in several statements.. do you think GC will really punish me for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work, but if those blocks can be identified as mostly independent from each other it should be possible to find a name which describes their duty and make them separate methods.

Smaller methods are more easy to reason about, and it is more easy to test their code in a testing framework.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your opinion but I also heard that more method also means more method calls, isnt that a degrade to performance when you create excessive methods & all of which need to be called for just 1 functions and not used by anyone else?

Comment: You are optimizing prematurely.  Write clear and concise code and put off the optimization until after you have something to measure.

Comment: @Marcos: You were talking about "taking long operation time" - now you switch the horses to short operations, performed gazillion of times? As @¢hris pointed in that direction: Clear code might be far better optimized by the JIT compiler. Don't do performance optimizations before proving where the bottleneck is, because most assumptions are wrong.